# Are callbacks of process.nextTick invoked in order?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

If you call `process.nextTick()` multiple times, are the callbacks executed in order?

In other words, does the Node event loop give the same priority to all calls to `process.nextTick`, and execute them in FIFO order?

For example:

```
process.nextTick(() => console.log('1'))
process.nextTick(() => console.log('2'))

process.nextTick(() =>
  process.nextTick(() => console.log('3'))
)

process.nextTick(() =>
  process.nextTick(() => console.log('4'))
)
```

Will this **always** print `1 2 3 4`?

Comment: Hmm, the [docs](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/topics/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick.md) talk about a queue... Can't find definite information on this subject though.

Comment: Even if they DO end up printing 1234 don't depend on it. Basically, NEVER depend on undocumented "features" because they may change anytime in the future due to optimizations etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of queue is being used is not written in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args), and I could not find an official source that explains it, so I took a look to the [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.x/lib/internal/process/next_tick.js) and it seems it is a FIFO queue as you pointed.

Check how the callbacks are pushed into the `nextTickQueue` array after each `nextTick()`, and how they are executed after in order in `_tickCallback()`, incrementing the index `tickInfo[kIndex]` in each iteration of the while loop.

I think in your example the third and fourth callbacks would not be at the same time in the queue with the first and second; but they would be executed in that order anyway.

By the way, even being a FIFO order of execution the expected way, this is an undocumented behaviour, so it is not recommended to rely on it; internal stuff can change anytime.

Comment: Thanks for the research! In other words, this is the current behavior, but there's no guarantee that it will remain so

Comment: You are welcome! Yeah, I agree with the comment made by @slebetman, this is internal stuff so it could change anytime. I added that explanation to the answer for future readers.